# Bugtracking tool with Git & TFS integration that is also easy to use for testers

Tags: git

We're a group of mobile and backend developers. Our company has a strong background with Microsoft and therefore TFS is being used for those who do backend & windows mobile development. 
The iOS and Android fraction are using Git.

We are on a quest for a bugtracking tool that suits our needs best. 
Ideally that would the tool could work with both versioning tools (linking TFS works item / Git commits to bugs / issues on the tracker). 
In addition, the tracker would have to be fairly easy to use for testers and QA guys.

I've googled around alot, but there doesn't really seem to be any TFS integration for bugtrackers any than, well, TFS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using [JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) in addition with [a git plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.xiplink.jira.git.jira_git_plugin) and [a TFS plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.spartez.jira.plugins.bork.tfs4jira). 
All three of them (Jira + 2 plugins) cost some money but we're quite happy with the combination.